# How can I put a Sum() in this linq query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I am looking to sum the "Status" field.

```
    Dim _detailRecords As New DataTable
    _detailRecords.Columns.Add("y")
    _detailRecords.Columns.Add("z")
    _detailRecords.Columns.Add("A", GetType(Int32))

    Dim workRow As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        workRow = _detailRecords.NewRow()
        workRow(0) = i.ToString()
        workRow(1) = "CustName" & i.ToString()
        workRow(2) = i + 1
        _detailRecords.Rows.Add(workRow)
    Next

    For i = 1 To 3
        workRow = _detailRecords.NewRow()
        workRow(0) = i.ToString()
        workRow(1) = "CustName" & i.ToString()
        workRow(2) = i + 1
        _detailRecords.Rows.Add(workRow)
    Next

Dim query8 As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From record As DataRow In _detailRecords _
    Group record By y = record.Field(Of String)("y"), _
                   z = record.Field(Of String)("z"), _
                   Status = record.Field(Of Int32)("Status") Into groupedRecords = Group _
Select groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault())
```

I'm also wanting to keep this as an IEnumerable of DataRow because I will be creating a datatable from it with

```
Dim yyyyy As DataTable = query8.CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum all the status fields from the records?

Comment: I am trying to sum all the status fields in the group

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [Aggregate clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531251.aspx)?

Comment: the Aggregate clause looks pretty cool, but it doesn't look like I could do a group by filter in it (or even a where). But it does look very promising for single computations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531251.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a call to the aggregate method you want and optionally add an alias to the result.

```
Dim query =
    From record In _detailRecords
    Group record
        By Y = record.Field(Of String)("y"),
           Z = record.Field(Of String)("z"),
           Status = record.Field(Of Int32)("Status")
        Into groupedRecords = Group,
             Sum(record.Field(Of Int32)("Status")) ' Get the sum of the Status values
    Select FirstRecord = groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault,
           Sum
```

Note that there are many ways this could be written, this is just one way.

Comment: Is there a way to get all 3 values in the same DataTable?

Comment: All 3 values? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: a linq (Datarow) result that contains y,z, status, instead of FirstRecord, and Sum.  I came up with a way where I create a new datatable and loop through the resultset to populate it, but i'd rather not have to do this

Comment: I suppose you can just change the `Select` clause back to what you had as `Select groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault` though you won't have the Sum available if you were to do that.  If you wanted to put that sum in that returned `DataRow`, you'd have to do this in multiple steps (i.e., it's not something you can do right in a single query)